# Need VBA code snippet for selenium to click on a web page element

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I previously used the following code snippet to click on a selector button in a web page that was opened in internet explorer.

```
Set inputSelector = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("idp") '<== the collection of input tags on the page
    For Each MyHTML_Element In inputSelector
        If MyHTML_Element.className = "idp" Then 
           MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

I tried to find the same button in the "idp" class with Selenium using

```
   Set inputBoxes = htmlDoc.FindElementByCss("idp").Text
```

which is from an example I found on-line.  This snippet generates a compiler error because .Text is a string and I'm seeking a collection.  What should I use in place of FindElementByCss().Text to return a collection?

```
Public Sub Sample()
    Dim pid As Long
    Dim pno As Long: pno = 17556
    Dim htmlDoc As WebDriver
    
'Create Selenium htmlDoc, Verify MS Edge Webdriver and continue
    Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("Selenium.WebDriver")
    pid = StartEdgeDriver(PortNo:=pno)
    If pid = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
'Specify URL, create Selenium html document and open webpage
    sLoginURL = "https://empowercentral.ussco.com/"
    htmlDoc.StartRemotely "http://localhost:" & pno & "/", "MicrosoftEdge"
    htmlDoc.Get sLoginURL    

Set inputSelector = htmlDoc.FindElementByCss("idp").Text
For Each MyHTML_Element In inputSelector
    If MyHTML_Element.className = "idp" Then 
       MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    End If
Next

    htmlDoc.FindElementById("userNameInput").SendKeys "username"
    htmlDoc.FindElementById("nextButton").Click
    htmlDoc.FindElementById("passwordInput").SendKeys "password"
    htmlDoc.FindElementById("submitButton").Click


End Sub
```

Here is the html from the website that I'm trying to scrape:

Sign in with one of these accounts

```
        <input id="hrdSelection" type="hidden">
        <div class="idp" tabindex="1" onkeypress="if (event &amp;&amp; (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13)) HRD.selection('http://login.essendant.com/adfs/services/trust');" onclick="HRD.selection('http://login.essendant.com/adfs/services/trust'); return false;"><img class="largeIcon float" src="/adfs/portal/images/idp/idp.png?id=3EADD3E829A20DF612C7A77960FF811E66E3EE6BAE2C33C9B20E7478BAC87548" alt="Customer or Supplier"><div class="idpDescription float"><span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Customer or Supplier</span></div></div><div class="idp" tabindex="2" onkeypress="if (event &amp;&amp; (event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13)) HRD.selection('AD AUTHORITY');" onclick="HRD.selection('AD AUTHORITY'); return false;"><img class="largeIcon float" src="/adfs/portal/images/idp/localsts.png?id=77809433F1EA22C491CA1C7A0836B144BB32E92C12110BF2A2D30810B030734D" alt="Active Directory"><div class="idpDescription float"><span class="largeTextNoWrap indentNonCollapsible">Essendant Associate</span></div></div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I notice in your second example, `inputSelector` is not defined.  Second, your search for "idp" uses `getElementsByClassName` in the first time (a collection), but `FindElementByCss` the second, a singular object is returned.  Hence, if `inputBoxes` is supposed to be what you're looping over, it could be why it doesn't work.  And, I could be wrong, but doesn't `.Text` return a string?  If so, `Set` is inappropriate because it is not an object.  Is there something I'm missing in this?  It just looks like a couple code errors, as the `inputSelector` you're looping over currently doesn't exist

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the desired element.

Comment: Update your question and include the HTML code from the webpage as requested by @undetectedSelenium . I used to do a workflow as you are trying when I used to work with Internet Explorer, but selenium is a bit different.